# Why does new role already have access to some databases in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
create role aaaaa_min_access_role;

grant role aaaaa_min_access_role to user me;
use role aaaaa_min_access_role;

show grants to role aaaaa_min_access_role;

show databases;
```

it results in 3 databases being outputted, the owner of those is accountadmin

wondering how?

when i do

```
REVOKE  USAGE ON DATABASE  DB_TEST  FROM ROLE  aaaaa_min_access_role;
REVOKE  USAGE ON SCHEMA  DB_TEST.SCHEMA  FROM ROLE  aaaaa_min_access_role;
REVOKE SELECT  ON ALL  TABLES  IN SCHEMA  DB_TEST.SCHEMA  FROM ROLE aaaaa_min_access_role;
```

it results in 0 objects being impacted. I'm able to execute select * from DB_TEST.SCHEMA.Table1 successfully

Answer (score 0):

Unless specified otherwise, new roles inherit from the PUBLIC role.

> PUBLIC
> Pseudo-role that is automatically granted to every user and every role in your account.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html#system-defined-roles

So the new role probably had at least some access to these databases through the PUBLIC role. You can check that by revoking the PUBLIC role from the new role you created.

Comment: but when i check the snowpipe UI there is no connection of this role to PUBLIC role

Comment: @ShivamAnand pls check this: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html#system-defined-roles PUBLIC is a pseudo-role that is automatically granted to every user and every role in your account.